# Calculating PPM of colloidal material in solution produced by electrolysis

Tags: electrolysis, silver

I am running an electrolysis between two silver electrodes.
The “electrolyte” is deionized water.
Ions are still formed as the CO2 of the air generates enough ions for a few µA of current.
During the electrolysis the ions are converted to metallic silver nanoparticles due to strong ultraviolet radiation.

I have the following variables:

1. Current in Ampere [A]
2. Time passed in seconds [s]
3. Coulomb [C or As]
4. Quantity of deionized water [l (liter)]
   I want to know:
5. On the anode dissolved silver in milligrams [mg]
6. PPM of silver in the deionized water [PPM]

In practice there will be some silver ions that make it from the anode to the cathode without “colliding” with an photon – so they will be depleted on the cathode.
However for the calculation I assume that all ions will get reduced to metallic nanoparticles and nothing will be depleted on the cathode.

How do I calculate the dissolved silver in mg and the PPM of the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that "ppm" is an ambiguous way to describe concentration and its usage is discouraged. See, for example, [my answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/112761/41328).

Comment: First no electrolysis can be made in deionized water. What voltage ? Under high tension, an ark may be obtained. Is it what you want ? Then you speak of ultraviolet radiation. Why ? Where ?  Why don't you add silver nitrate in the solution ? Finally what are you trying to do ?