# How to draw a skeletal formula with thick lines and high resolution?

Tags: structural-formula

Consider the caffeine molecule skeletal formula as depicted in the [Wikimedia Commons .svg](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Caffeine_structure.svg#mw-jump-to-license) file. Suppose that I want to replicate this skeletal formula with a high resolution and **thicker lines**.

I have found several online tools to draw molecules, but none of them allows the user to adjust line thickness (and, moreover, the resolution of the final output is generally not very high). I have also thought of using Tikz in LaTex, but going this route is really difficult and time-consuming, particularly if one wishes to replicate several skeletal formulae.

*How would you draw a skeletal formula with thick lines and high resolution?*

P.S: I’m sorry if this is not the correct place to ask such a question. If this is the case, feel free to tell me which SE site might be adequate for my question.

Thank you all very much for your time.

Comment: [Software list](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37880) for drawing from scratch with desired graphical features. As for this caffeine SVG, you can tweak line thickness in any vector editor such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org).

Comment: @andselisk  I disagree with closing this question because its answer can be found within a list of source materials, since that's true of many questions answered on Chem SE.   For instance, if you're going to close this question because its answer can be found within the materials listed at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112760/is-1-ppb-equal-to-1-μg-kg/112761#112761, shoudn't you also close https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112760/is-1-ppb-equal-to-1-μg-kg/112761#112761? Its answer can also be found within one of the sources in the former link (IUPAC Green Book).

Comment: @Hector Here's how you can make use of the resources listed in the link andselisk supplied: (1) go to the software list he linked. (2) Identify the subset of those that do chemical drawing. (3) Google: '[software name] adjust line widths in structural formulas'. If you do this with, e.g., MarvinSketch, you will find this link, docs.chemaxon.com/display/docs/drawing-settings.md , which indicates these can be adjusted in MarvinSketch using "Wireframe bond thickness", which "Sets the width of all bonds and lines."

Comment: @theorist I see your point. Let me reframe my closing decision as motivation for OP to narrow down their request. Shall they decide to ask how to tweak the *detailed* appearance of a bond within a *specific* piece of software, I'd immediately reconsider my close-vote. Currently I see the question broad enough to be a duplicate without much of a stretch. Anyway, please feel free to cast a reopening vote if you still disagree.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I ended up using a vector editor to change the undesired features of the original svg files I found in Wiki Commons.