# How to prepare standard sample of benzene for gas sampling bag?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, gas-laws, concentration

I need to make a 1 ppm gaseous standard of benzene in nitrogen gas within a Tedlar® gas sampling bag. Is this as simple as injecting 1 μL of neat benzene liquid into 1 L of nitrogen gas within the bag?

Or do I need to weigh out the benzene liquid and use a calculation including the molecular mass of benzene?

Comment: You need 1 microlitre of benzene **vapor** per 1 L of N2 at the same conditions as the used N2, if ppm(v/v) is assumed. Or recalculated V for different p or T. I suggest to use a kind of concentrated  benzene vapor in N2 mixture and use this for final standard.

Comment: [Here we go with ppm again](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/112761)…

Comment: Consider obtaining a crash course about gas laws and metrology basics  or delegation of  the task.